# Themes for Ubuntu Notification System

Tags: ubuntu, themes, notifications

I am running Ubuntu 9.04 and absolutely love the new notification system. However, I would like to play around with the themes of the notifications. 
Is this possible yet? Where can I mess around with the them styles?

**Edit**: I actually found that the new notification system (notify-osd) has had both the style and position hard coded. I hope this changes in a future release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change the theme of the notification area just yet. However you can [download the source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jaunty/notify-osd) and play with the messages yourself (and if you do add support for themes, give Canonical your source and see if they will implement it).

**Edit:** Also look at the [wiki on how to change stuff](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD). (Thanks to @[lvo](https://superuser.com/users/1548/ivo)).

Comment: Or read the wiki on how to change stuff ;-) https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD

Comment: @lvo: Updated my answer to include your comment.